# Given curve on a regular surface $S$ is a line of curvature in $S$ if and only if the ruled surface is developable

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

$\vec\alpha : I \rightarrow S \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a curve on a regular surface S

and the ruled surface generated {$\vec\alpha(u), \vec N(u)$}, $\vec N(u)$ is the  normal to the surface $S$ at $\vec\alpha$

I need to show that, $\vec\alpha(I) \subset \mathbb S$ is a line of curvature in $S$ $\iff$ this ruled surface is developable.

My Attempt:

$\vec x(u,v) = \vec\alpha(u) + \vec vN(u)$

and

$(\vec N,\vec N',\vec\alpha') = 0$

If $\vec\alpha$ is a line of curvature of $S$ then,

$\vec N'(u)=d\vec N_p(\vec \alpha'(u))=\lambda(u)+\vec \alpha'(u)$

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your ruled surface is parametrized by $r(u,v)=\alpha(u)+vN(\alpha(u))$, so its tangent planes at points $(u,v)$ are spanned by

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}(u,v)=\alpha'(u)+vDN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))\text{ and }\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}(u,v)=N(\alpha(u)).$$

The tangent space at $(u,0)$ is spanned by $\alpha'(u)$ and $N(\alpha(u))$. Thus, the surface will be developable if and only if the vector $DN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))$ is a linear combination of $\alpha'(u)$ and $N(\alpha(u))$. Since

$$DN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))=\underbrace{[DN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))]^\top}_{\in T_{(u,v)}S}+\underbrace{[DN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))]^\perp}_{\in\,\mathrm{span}(N(\alpha(u)))},$$

this is equivalent to $[DN_{\alpha(u)}(\alpha'(u))]^\top=S_{u}(\alpha'(u))$ being a multiple of $\alpha'(u)$, i.e. $\alpha'$ is made of eigenvectors of the shape operator, or again $\alpha$ is a line of curvature.

Comment: Thank you... But I don't think this solution will be accepted, it seems higher level maths? I need to use $\vec x(u,v) = \vec\alpha(u) + \vec vN(u)$ and  $(\vec N,\vec N',\vec\alpha') = 0$

If $\vec\alpha$ is a line of curvature of $S$ then, $\vec N'(u)=d\vec N_p(\vec \alpha'(u))=\lambda(u)+\vec \alpha'(u)$ I found a solution but can't interpret. It says $\vec \alpha'=\lambda\vec N'$ that implies $(\vec N,\vec N',\vec\alpha') = 0$ but how?

Comment: What is $\lambda$ in your definition?  I think that the hypothesis of $\alpha$ being a line of curvature rewrites itself as: there exist functions $\lambda,\nu$ such that $d\vec N_p(\vec \alpha'(u))=\lambda(u)\vec \alpha'(u)+\nu(u)\vec N(\alpha(u))$, thus $(\vec N,\vec N',\vec\alpha')=(\vec N,\lambda\vec\alpha'+\nu\vec N,\vec\alpha')=0$ (trying to use your notations).

Comment: I don't know. I found a solution in this link in second page http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~degt/math345/2000-f.pdf    May it be one of the principle curvatures? I need to write such a solution but I need to know what it's, can you explain this solution?

Comment: It seems to be a scalar function $\lambda:I\to\mathbb{R}$. Also you document uses specific notations which have been introduced in the related course (or at least it seems to me), so your best shot is to read that part of the course or to find someone used to this notations. Perhaps make a new post where you explicitly state that you are interested in this problem and you found the solution in this specific correction.

Comment: And in your comment how it ended up being all $ zero$?

Comment: I think the notation $(A,B,C)$ stands for $\det(A,B,C)$, so if one of the three is a linear combination of the other two, it must equals $0$. It is again trying to guess what the notations mean.

Comment: Ah, may it be det? Does both $N'$ and $N$ being zero makes sense?

Comment: The definiton is in this book at page 194 if you have time. Thanks for all the help, I will try to figure it out by myself  http://www2.ing.unipi.it/griff/files/dC.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is $\det$. do Carmo directly takes $\det(N,N',\alpha')=0$ as a definition for developable surface (without mentionning lines of curvature), which is equivalent to $N'$ being a linear combination of $N$ and $\alpha'$ , and my answer explain how this is equivalent to $\alpha$ being a line of curvature (also, if your first correction uses do Carmo's notations, I don't agree with the correction). Try to get a correct definition of what a curvature line is, then you can try to glue the pieces together :)

Comment: Thanks you :) Did you understand the solution in this link? http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~degt/math345/2000-f.pdf I mean, why $\alpha'=\lambda N'$ implies to $det(N,N',\alpha')=0$ ?